# Code to count how many uniformly distributed random numbers (0,1), observed before a value larger than 0.99 are observed without WHILE loop

Tags: python, typeerror

i need to write a code to count how many uniformly distributed random numbers (0,1), observed before a value larger than 0.99 are observed without using a WHILE loop. But i get the error message: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. Anyone that can see where the problem is?

---

```
import numpy as np
x = random.uniform(0,1)
count = 0
target = 0.99



for i in range(x):
    x[i] = random.uniform(0,1)
    if x[i] <= target:
        count += 1
        break
    else: 
        continue

print('%d uniformly random numbers observed before observing af value larger than 0.99' % count)
```

Comment: You are calling `range(x)` when `x` came from `random.uniform`

Comment: in `for-loop`, you use x and x between `0,1`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `for-loop` use this:

```py
import itertools
import numpy as np
import random

count = 0
target = 0.99


for i in itertools.count(start=1):
    x = random.uniform(0,1)
    if x > target:
        break
    count += 1


print('%d uniformly random numbers observed before observing af value larger than 0.99' % count)
```

with `while-loop` use this:

```py
import numpy as np
import random

count = 0
target = 0.99



while 1:
    x = random.uniform(0,1)
    if x <= target:
        count += 1
    else: 
        break

print('%d uniformly random numbers observed before observing af value larger than 0.99' % count)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I can't use while loops though, cause the assignment is to do it without while-loop :)

Comment: @Ragn, I edit the code block, maybe this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use a while loop?

```
import numpy as np
import random

count = 0
target = 0.99
x = random.uniform(0,1)

while x <= target:
    count += 1
    x = random.uniform(0,1)

print('%d uniformly random numbers observed before observing af value larger than 0.99' % count)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I can't use while loops though, cause the assignment is to do it without while-loop :)